# Unwrapping Plist and finding object

Tags: arrays, swift, plist

Getting hugely frustrated trying to translate objective c to swift. I have the following code that works for objective c.

```
NSMutableArray *path = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sequence List" ofType:@"plist"]];

//Shuffle the array of questions
numberSequenceList = [self shuffleArray:path];

currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;

if (Round==1) {
    //Take first object in shuffled array as the first question
    NSMutableArray *firstQuestion = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[numberSequenceList objectAtIndex:0]];

    //Find question and populate text view
    NSString *string = [firstQuestion objectAtIndex:0];

    self.lblNumber.text = string;

    //Find and store the answer
    NSString *findAnswer = [firstQuestion objectAtIndex:1];

    Answer = [findAnswer intValue];
}
```

But I can't seem to get this to work in swift. I can pull out the contents of the plist using

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sequence List", ofType: "plist")
```

But I can't see that there is an equivalent to objectAtIndex in swift. If I try the following I get an error message advising "string does not have a member named subscript", which apparently means I need to unwrap path.

```
let firstQuestion = path[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods you are calling, like `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource`, return optionals, because  they might fail.  In Objective-C, that failure is indicated by a `nil`, whereas Swift uses optionals.

So in your example:

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sequence List", ofType: "plist")
```

`path` is of type `Optional<String>` (or `String?`) and not of type `String`.  `Optional<String>` doesn’t have a subscript method (i.e. doesn’t support `[ ]`).  To use the string within, you have to check if the optional contains a value (i.e. the call to `pathForResource` was successful):

```
// the if let syntax checks if the optional contains a valid 
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sequence List", ofType: "plist”) {
    // use path, which will now be of type String
}
else {
    // deal with pathForResource failing
}
```

You can read more about optionals in introduction of [the Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_467).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. however, when I try to use the if function I now get a message advising 'Subscript is unavailable: cannot subscript string with an int'. How can I use the first object in the string?

Comment: `first(mystring)` (which again, returns an optional because the string might be empty).  Or `mystring[mystring.startIndex]` – strings aren’t integer-indexable because they aren’t guaranteed to be random-access (because certain characters can be different byte lengths)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't translated the entire first line from Objective-C.  You are missing the call to `NSMutableArray` which creates the array from the contents of the file.  The original code is confusing because it calls the contents of the file `path` when it is really questions.  Try this:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sequence List", ofType: "plist") {
    let questions = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)

    //Shuffle the array of questions
    numberSequenceList = self.shuffleArray(questions)

    currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1

    if Round == 1 {
        //Take first object in shuffled array as the first question
        let firstQuestion = numberSequenceList[0] as NSArray

        //Find question and populate text view
        let string = firstQuestion[0] as NSString

        self.lblNumber.text = string

        //Find and store the answer
        let findAnswer = firstQuestion[1] as NSString

        Answer = findAnswer.intValue
    }
}
```